# How to process empty fields in integer column of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a column in a table that contains numeric values. However, some fields are empty. I want to read all fields in this column into integer variable. How should I manage empty fields?

```
int total = tableModel.getValueAt(currentRow, currentCol).toString().equals("") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(tablePaxModel.getValueAt(currentRow, currentCol).toString());
```

Comment: how about just reading the value as String first. then check for nulls or blanks and finally parse to appropriate int. for example you can put 0 where ever you see null. also, where does this int go? can a default value for null or blank affect any other calculations?

Comment: @AbtPst: I think that my solution is what you suggest. Am I right? I just wanted to be sure that the way I'm doing it is correct. Blanks can only affect "total".

Comment: correct, that is the straightforward way to do it. as long as you put a default value lie 0, it should not affect any additions that you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
something like

try {
    String val = tablePaxModel.getValueAt(currentRow, currentCol).toString();

    int temp=0;
    if(val.isEmpty() || val == null)
       temp=0;

    else
    {
    temp = Integer.parseInt(val);
    }

    total = total + temp
}

catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

something like that. i have taken some assumptions with your code but you can modify as needed

Comment: Also, "temp" needs to be changed otherwise it will always be 0 unless you assign it. `int temp` has the default value of 0, so even if the value is null or empty, its always adding zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
     try 
     {
        String valueInCell = (String)tablePaxModel.getValueAt(currentRow, currentCol);

        if(valueInCell == null || valueInCell.isEmpty())
        {
            valueInCell = "0";
        }

        int tempCellValue = Integer.parseInt(valueInCell);

        total += tempCellValue;

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```